# pl/sql - to_date not working with execute immediate parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, ora-00904

i wanna be able to execute my below proc like so:

```
exec procname('29-JAN-2011');
```

proc code is:

```
PROCEDURE procname(pardate VARCHAR2) IS

  vardate DATE := to_date(pardate, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  SQLS VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN    

  SQLS := 'SELECT cola, colb
             FROM tablea 
            WHERE TRUNC(coldate) = TRUNC(TO_DATE('''||pardate||''',''DD/MON/YYYY''))';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLS;

END;
```

It keeps throwing error:

> ORA-00904: "JAN": invalid identifier.

It compiles, but it throws the error when I run this command:

```
EXEC procname('29-JAN-2011');
```

Comment: This isn't the actual code, right? It wouldn't compile.

Comment: I know this is just an example, but does that procedure have to be dynamic SQL? It would work just fine as a regular procedure.

Comment: it needs to be dynamic because i'm gonna make it so the column names are unknown at runtime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You declare a variable which casts the input parameter to a date: why not use it?

Also, the TRUNC() applied to a date removes the time element.  You don't need it here because the value you're passing has no time.

So, your code should be:

```
PROCEDURE procname(pardate VARCHAR2) IS

  vardate DATE := to_date(pardate, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
  SQLS VARCHAR2(4000)  := 'select cola, colb FROM tablea 
           WHERE TRUNC(coldate) = :1';

   l_a tablea.cola%type;
   l_b tablea.colb%type;
BEGIN    
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLS 
      into l_a, l_b
      using vardate;
END;
```

Specifying the dynamic SQL statement with a bind variable and executing it with the  USING syntax is a lot more efficient.  Note that we still have to SELECT into some variables.

Comment: As a side note, that trunc() may avoid the use of an index over coldate. He may consider the trick "... where coldate between :1 and :2 + 0.99999" using vardate, vardate .

Answer (score 1):

You're using two different notations in the two calls to `to_date`. I think one of them (the second) is wrong.

Comment: I mean, one of them is DD-MON-YYYY and the other is DD/MON/YYYY. The input uses dashes, not slashes, so I'd think the second is wrong.

Comment: Could be a language setting problem too. Do you live in a country where january is not shortened to JAN?